# Not able to use ids to pass value between page

Tags: asp.net

I have images which I am using to navigate to next page using href:-

```
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx" id="abc">
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx" id="xyz">
```

Now I am want to pass some values so that I can display on some information depending on which image user has clicked.

```
        var id = Request.QueryString["id"];

    if (id == Request.QueryString["abc"])
    {
        Label1.Text = "abc";
    }

    if (id == Request.QueryString["xyz"])
    {
        Label1.Text = "xyz";
    }
```

But not getting expected result.

Comment: Can probably be closed under this official close reason (effectively the old "too localised"): _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass those on the querystring

```
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx?id=abc" id="abc">
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx?id=xyz" id="xyz">
```

Your if condition seems to be a bit wrong to me.  Do this

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
if (id == "abc")
{
    Label1.Text = "abc";
}
else if (id == "xyz")
{
    Label1.Text = "xyz";
}
```

Or if you are simply showing whatever comes in the querystring , you can do like this

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
Label1.Text =id;
```

Comment: @user1374181: your if checking is wrong. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `href` attributes need to include the query string, something like:

```
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx?abc=something" id="abc">text</a>
```